# Can one add email contacts to the Kitkat Email app? (as in iOS7)

Tags: contacts, email

As a newbie to Android with a shiny new phone (Prestigio 5508 Duo) I have begun setting it up ready for use. I have added my BT Mail account details and the system hooked up and displayed mails straight away.  Excellent!  However, there seems to be no option within the email account to include the details of where the Contacts file associated with my email are kept by BT. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: What contacts file associated with your mail? You might have to describe this in more detail for those of us who don't use BT.

Comment: Alternatively, if you describe what you did in iOS, that would help us understand exactly what settings you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Android tends to work better with Google's mail (Gmail). I don't have any knowledge specifically of BT as I am a Yank, so I can't address that. I just read up on the BT/Yahoo split and looked around for a couple of minutes for a solution for you, but it didn't look good.

I would recommend Gmail and then grit your teeth and make the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Having now used my phone for a bit longer it appears that the on board email client that I have looking to BT, will use the Android address book.  The same seems to be true for a Yahoo webmail account I have set up.

Thus the answer to my original question is to export the address book as a file, upload it to the phone and import it into Google Mail contacts.